# Which type Most Easy Index, .htm or .php or .html

Tags: indexing, google-search

I have recently made a site with paid hosting. Some of the posts are very old .php file extension in the google search engine index.
According to you, which are the most reliable and fast in the index?

Answer (score 0):

I believe all files are indexed no matter the file extension. They are all reliable and equally fast. The file extension should be after your choice of technology. If you need php on your website use .php, if you don't have php in your website code use .html. It's as easy as that.